# How to load data to Dynamo DB Table with Global and Local Secondary Indexes ??

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created some tables in Dynamo DB using AWS console and defined some global and secondary indexes.

Now the problem is how to load data in those tables using AWS SDK of java.
I went through the Developer guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Introduction.html) of Dynamo DB but I could not find how to load data when your table has global secondary indexes.

Code to load table with data is :

```
  Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tableName);
  Item item = new Item().withPrimaryKey("Name", "Amazon DynamoDB")
                        .withString("Category", "Amazon Web Services")
                        .withNumber("Threads", 2)
                        .withNumber("Messages", 4)
                        .withNumber("Views", 1000);
  table.putItem(item);
```

Now suppose in my table if I have defined Views as Global Secondar Index.
So the same code will work or there are some different method to deal with this kind of use cases ??

Comment: What do you mean by ``*"same code will work"*? Do you mean writing to the GSI?

Comment: yaa..  I mean the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table has secondary indexes (being Local or Global) they will be automatically created/maintained as you insert data in the table itself. DynamoDB will manage your indexes automatically making sure they are consistent with whatever you have in the table.

However, another completely different issue (that you should be careful about) is how to properly load data into DynamoDB tables:

> There are times when you load data from other data sources into
>   DynamoDB. Typically, DynamoDB partitions your table data on multiple
>   servers. When uploading data to a table, you get better performance if
>   you upload data to all the allocated servers simultaneously. For
>   example, suppose you want to upload user messages to a DynamoDB table.
>   You might design a table that uses a hash and range type primary key
>   in which UserID is the hash attribute and the MessageID is the range
>   attribute.

More details on [Distribute Write Activity During Data Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.DataUpload)

Here you can find some additional information about Secondary Indexes to complement what you already know:

> For efficient access to data in a table, Amazon DynamoDB creates and
>   maintains indexes for the primary key attributes. This allows
>   applications to quickly retrieve data by specifying primary key
>   values. However, many applications might benefit from having one or
>   more secondary (or alternate) keys available, to allow efficient
>   access to data with attributes other than the primary key. To address
>   this, you can create one or more secondary indexes on a table, and
>   issue Query or Scan requests against these indexes.
>
> A secondary index is a data structure that contains a subset of
>   attributes from a table, along with an alternate key to support Query
>   operations. With a secondary index, queries are no longer restricted
>   to the table primary key; you can also retrieve the data using the
>   alternate key defined by the secondary index. A table can have
>   multiple secondary indexes, which gives your applications access to
>   many different query patterns.
>
> The data in a secondary index consists of attributes that are
>   projected, or copied, from the table into the index. When you create a
>   secondary index, you define the alternate key for the index, along
>   with any other attributes that you want to be projected in the index.
>   DynamoDB copies these attributes into the index, along with the
>   primary key attributes from the table. You can then query or scan the
>   index just as you would query or scan a table.

The section [Improving Data Access with Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) should provide helpful details on how to properly define GSI's (including concepts like *projections* and etc).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write directly to GSIs, even if they are defined for a table.

Instead, DynamoDB will automatically propagate item insertions, updates, and deletions to GSIs, depending on the `ProjectionType` set in each GSI. As long as you have defined the GSIs in the `CreateTable` operation, or added them in an `UpdateTable` operation, the GSIs will reflect items you put into the base table, depending on the `ProjectionType`.

Comment: Hey, I am new to Dynamo DB. I didn't understand your answer properly. I didn't understand the concept of projected Attributes. can you please throw some light on this ?

Comment: As per as I understand projected Attributes are those attributes which we can get by querying using secondary Indexes.

Comment: Projections in GSIs are described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.Projections) and projections in LSIs are described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Projections). Your understanding is correct, attributes you project appear in secondary indexes.